# Download missing driver files link in IntelliJ broken by fire wall

Tags: intellij-idea, maven-repository

I am trying to connect to my company's Snowflake instance using IntelliJ ultimate. our firewall blocks downloads from repo1.maven.com, because we maintain an internal repo that is regularly scanned for vulnerabilities... All great so far, and I get why they block un vetted sources.

How do I convince IntelliJ to look for the drivers in the internal repo?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Snowflake's Documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/jdbc/jdbc-download#integrating-the-driver-into-a-maven-project) its' driver is a regular Maven artifact, so assuming you have specified your internal repository in the Project's `pom.xml` and the driver is present there, Intellij should not have any problems downloading it.
Intellij is also supports native integration with Snowflake, which you might find useful. Please refer to [Intellij's Documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/snowflake.html) for more details.

Another option is to download the driver using your browser and pointing Intellij to it directly, which you can do by:

1. Opening "[Data Sources and Drivers](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/data-sources-and-drivers-dialog.html)" dialog
2. Navigating to "Drivers" tab -> Snowflake
3. Clicking "+" under the "Driver Files" section and choosing the JAR or a native driver file you've downloaded.

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work... I have been able to hack their jdbc-drivers.xml file and add an entry for the snowflake-jdbc-3.13.32.jar file that points to my internal repo and gotten that file downloaded to IntelliJ's satisfaction. However, I have not been able to achieve the same result for jna-platform-5.8.0.jar.

Comment: Also I have opened a ticket with JetBrains on this. I will try to update this with an answer once I have a working solution

Comment: @cptully How's that going?

Comment: I never got it resolved. But then the team I was on that was using Snowflake got disbanded. So, from my perspective, the issue just went away....